# how to tell active record to make an update instead of insert on a (not) new record after dup(ing) an other one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Or: How does Active record decide what to use `update` or `insert`?

I am using UUIDs as keys.

I generate UUIDs client side for new objects to allow asynch work with the server/db.

Example: The user adds a new triangle to his drawing, I create this object set a uuid (lets say AAA), place it in editor and the user can work further. Then I send the update to the server. So the user does not have to wait the RTT.

The user fills the triangle green, I draw that -> AJAX to server (Update (AAA))

The use makes a copy of the green triangle, I copy the object set a new UUID and send an AJAX copy AAA to BBB

the user hits undo - remove BBB from drawing send AJAX remove BBB (but its not deleted its just marked for deletion as a standard in my app)

the user hits redo -> I copy the object set a new UUID (BBB again) and send an AJAX copy AAA to BBB

BANG duplicate key

Server side I make a dup, set the id and save

```
new_rec=old_rec.dup
new_rec.id=new_id #BBB
new_rec.save (BANG because insert)
```

So what I need is something like

```
new_rec=old_rec.dup
new_rec.id=new_id #BBB

new_rec.set_method_to_update if Record.exist?(new_id)

new_rec.save (BANG because insert)
```

I know, that there are workarounds but is it possible the easy way?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK rails doesn't let you change the `persisted` characteristic of a record.  You'll need to retrieve the record if it exists and update it.

```
new_rec = Record.find(new_id)

if new_rec
  new_rec.deleted = false
else
  new_rec = old_rec.dup
  new_rec.id = new_id
end

new_rec.save
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the duplicate entries on server end, considering only the primary keys as identifiers in the DB objects. Fetch the data with ID and create one if not found.

Assuming you are using Rails 4, you can use this method [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

As i see your question, on a different note: first thing you can do is instead of making ajax calls on every or specific operations. Put a sync of say 5-10 seconds of work done on the interface, using something like angular/backbone to handle the UI level model hierarchy which you have designed. Replace the temporary UUID's on the browser from the server ID's on sync or keep a mapping of both which could be slightly helpful but somewhat messy to maintain.

Comment: I use the UUIDs not to have the troubles with syncing temp keys (I did before, then it got wild and ugly  so decided to migrate to UUID id). the duplicate entry 'happens' because of the undo/redo and that I do not delete records directly in DB.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed - found accidently: `@new_record`

Set to false and all is fine ...

Usage in Record (model.rb)

```
def clear_new_if_not
    @new_record=!self.class.exists?(self.id)
end
```

and logic above:

```
new_rec=old_rec.dup
new_rec.id=new_id #BBB

new_rec.clear_new_if_not()

new_rec.save (no bang)
```